# Christoffel symbols knowing Line element (check my result)

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I'm asked to find all the non-zero Christoffel symbols given the following line element:

$ds^2=2x^2dx^2+y^4dy^2+2xy^2dxdy$

The result I have obtained is that the only non-zero component of the Christoffel symbols is:

$\Gamma^x_{xx}=\frac{1}{x}$

**Is this correct?**

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's incorrect, there are more non-zero symbols.  Also, in my previous answer, I thought you meant to just check the one entry you specified.  Here are all the symbols.  I suggest looking into CAS's if you plan to compute many symbols.

[image]

Comment: Ohhhh Thank you so much. I've just seen my mistake. You've helped me a lot! And thanks for the code too!!

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? For these Christoffel symbols, are all the components of the Riemann curvature tensor zero? $R^\alpha_{\beta\gamma\delta}$

Comment: @ConfusedPhysicist it's not really appropriate to have extended answers in the comments.  Furthermore, I don't have the time right now to code up the RIemann tensor but I suggest, if you have Mathematica, to use GRQUICK which is here: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/8329/